# aws lambda update-function-configuration receives AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, vpc

I want to grant vpc access for my lambda function. I use the following aws cli command.

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration \
--function-name SampleFunction \
--vpc-config SubnetIds=subnet-xxxx,SecurityGroupIds=sg-xxxx
```

But I receive the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: Your access has been denied by
>   EC2, please make sure your request credentials have permission to
>   DescribeSecurityGroups for sg-xxxx. EC2 Error Code:
>   UnauthorizedOperation. EC2 Error Message: You are not authorized to
>   perform this operation.

I have granted the following permission to both my lambda role and the user who execute the aws command.

```
    - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
    - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
    - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
    - "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
```

I further tried to grant full access to both the lambda role and the user. But still received the same error

Can anyone suggest what else I can try?

Comment: Are you trying to run it from an EC2-Instance? If so, the Instance-Profile needs to have the right permissions.

Comment: @Chun-Kit Chung, how did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your users IAM policy needs further permissions.

For example ec2:CreateSecurityGroup & etc. Have a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html#ex-security-groups) documentation to add requred permissions.

Comment: thanks @Ashan
Did you mean adding permission for the user that runs this task? 
I added EC2 permissions to CloudFormation (I use CodeStar) but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jun I meant the IAM permission for the user who runs the above mentioned CLI command.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to add the pipeline / worker role / user which is deploying the lambda function)  have access to network related policies. The lambda function should itself suffice with managed policy - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

- Action:

  - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
  - ec2:DescribeSubnets
  - ec2:DescribeVpcs
    Effect: Allow
    Resource: '*'

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. Despite the IAM policy for the user having the required permissions, I could not use the aws cli to crate a lambda function with a VPC config (aws lambda create-function) *or* modify an existing function to add a VPC config (aws lambda update-function-configuration).

The only way I could get this to work was to create the lambda function without a VPC config. I then modified the function to add the VPC config information (vpc, subnet and security groups) via the AWS console (in Lambda > Fucntions > My Function > Network). I was only able to use the console to do this, introducing a manual step in an otherwise fully automated process.

To answer some of the questions above about which user needs the ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups and related permissions. It is the user running the cli command or logged in to the console. The function does not need a policy providing these permissions. The only special permissions needed for a function with a VPC config are:

- ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
- ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
- ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface

These allow the function to create [ENIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html) within your VPC using the subnet and security group you provide as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Both the Lambda funtion's role and the user role (either cloudformation or cmline user) must have:

```
          - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
          - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
          - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
          - ec2:DescribeSubnets
```

or ec2:* if ok for your use case'security

I had the same issue deploying a lambda with a VPC config using SAM/cloudformation and resolved it by adding this above.

on github issue some people say it is because of cloudformation order creation it is not (or maybe not anymore because I tested adding 20 dummy resource and still the same issue only resolved by adding the permissions above)

cheers,